# Why is blazor.server.js blocking my other js files?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have Blazor Server Web App Project that contains this default javascript link:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

When I remove the link, my other js files load correctly, but if I add it back then they do not load. It does not matter if I add `blazor.server.js` **before** or **after** my js links.

**HOW TO RECREATE MY SCENARIO:**

1. Create default **Blazor Server Web App**
2. Add a new `demo.js` file to `wwwroot` and enter this js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#clickme").on("click", function () {
        alert("Handler for the 'Click Me' button is called.");
    });
});
```

3. Add `demo.js` to `_Host.cshtml` like this: `<script src="~/demo.js"></script>`
4. Create a button in `/Index` or `/Counter` and add: `id="clickme"`
5. Make sure that `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` is present in `_Host.cshtml`

*Buid and Run.*

**Result 01:**

1. The Blazor Server Web App will run but when you click the button, js code is not called.

Now, remove `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`, build and run.

**Result 02:**

1. The Blazor Server Web App will run and when you click the button, js code is called correctly.

I want to include `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` and other js files and make them work.

*What could be the problem?*

**I am using:**

1. Visual Studio IDE 2022
2. Blazor Server Web App
3. .NET 7

Comment: Why are you still using jQuery in 2023? Also, using jQuery with Blazor causes issues due to how they handle the DOM.

Comment: @Dai: For simplicity I provided this sample but I am using a modern web template which has js files conflicting with blazor.server.js, I am using this template: https://themeforest.net/item/vuexy-vuejs-html-laravel-admin-dashboard-template/23328599

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Blazor works and what purpose it serves. You already posted another question on Stack very similar to this. If you want to access javascript from Blazor you need to use JSInterop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0 but judging from your other question this isn't going to achieve what you're trying to do. I posted a comment on your other question to clear it up a bit further.

Comment: @Waragi: I appreciate your input. There reason why I posted this question is because I noticed blazor.server.js had such an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12966 but I thought I missed out on the solution somehow. With my current problem I have tried to disable blazor.server.js then manually enable it and then chain other js files. Some js files where added successfully but had undefined errors on components. This led me to post this question hoping that I missed something. thanks for your input anyways.

Comment: @RussellChidhakwa if you're just trying to use the theme static assets, you can place references to them in the _Host.cshtml. If you wanted to use a Javascript framework like Vue with Blazor Server you're basically out of luck.